# How do you query a nested type field from a record set returned from a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, nested-table

I have the following types defined:

```
TYPE N_TXT IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(300);

TYPE N_TYPE IS RECORD ( FIELD_1 VARCHAR2 (100)
                       , FIELD_2 N_TXT);

TYPE T_TYPE IS TABLE OF N_TYPE;
```

And created a function to return a table record type:

```
FUNCTION fn_test (p_1 IN SMALLINT) RETURN t_type PIPELINED ....
```

I can then query the result set from this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE (fn_test(P_1));
```

to retrieve all the data.

If field_2 had multiple records e.g. 3 records the out put will return something like this:

```
FIELD_2

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

N_TYPE(record1, record2, record3)
```

How do you unwrapped field_2 to select individual records from the nested type for processing?

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH 
    ft 
AS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM TABLE fn_test(P_1)
    )
SELECT 
    ft.FIELD_1 f1, 
    A.column_value f2
FROM 
    ft, TABLE(ft.FIELD_2) A
```